# Error: write EPIPE & MongoError: pool is draining, new operations prohibited

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Please help resolve this error related to mongo pool is draining.

Project Stack: MEAN Stack

Models involved in this case:

1. Investor:
2. PmlaDb: Stores a set of data in which each investor should be searched. The collection has around 815K + documents. Total Collection size is approx. 140MB.
3. PmlaCheck: Stores result of search performed for an Investor in PmlaDB.

**Process on server:**

1. Method 1: First controller method receives req.body, forwards the reqBody to next method-2 synchronously for processing and immly sends response informing the user that the request is being processed.
2. Method 2: In req.body an array of Investor IDs are received. Some preparatory code is executed.
   Then in For loop for investorIDs, each Investor document is retrieved from Investors collection and
   the necessary data is forwarded to method-3 for performing detailed search in pmlaDb.
3. Method 3: Single Investor search is performed in pmlaDb and result data is returned to Method-2.
4. Back in Method 2 inside the for loop: Generates a new record for pmlaCheck collection for this investor using result data returned by method 3 and saves it.

**About ERROR:**

1. When this code is tested ON MY LAPTOP it works fine without any error. But error occurs while testing on the webapp on VPS.
2. it takes approx 5-7 seconds to complete each Investor search
3. when approx 35 investorIds are searched there is no error.
4. the error occurs when more than 35 investors are searched.
5. pls consider multiple users triggering this process on VPS simultaneously. As of now when error occured there were none.

**Node method 1:**

```
async function pmlaCheckMany(reqBody, user){
  NowPmlaCheckMany(reqBody, refNo, user)
}
```

**Node method 2:** This is a very long method with reference to other methods within, hence not putting all the details below. Indicated all await calls.

```
async function NowPmlaCheckMany(reqBody, refNo, user) {
  const {investorIds, pmlaDbsTBC, checkType} = reqBody;


  if(investorIds.length <= 0) return;

  console.log( user.userName + ' STARTED NowPmlaCheckMany for ' + reqBody.investorIds.length + ' investors at ' + new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-IN', { timeStyle: 'medium', dateStyle: 'medium', timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata' }).format(new Date())
  )

  const userAuthData = await clientService.getMsClientIds(user, ['cob', 'pmla'], 'pmlaService.pmlaCheckMany');

  const dbData = await PmlaDbMaster.find({isActive: true}).sort('ctrlName').lean().exec();

  ///// pass pmla DBs to be checked params
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////
  if(checkType === 'V1') {
    await checkIfPmlaDbsExist(dbData, pmlaDbsTBC);

  } else if(checkType === 'V2') {
    // console.log(' going to checkIfPmlaDbsExistNEW')
    await checkIfPmlaDbsExistNEW(dbData, pmlaDbsTBC);
  
  } 

  const currentPmlaFiles = await getCurrentPmlaFiles(dbData, pmlaDbsTBC, user);

  let fullPmlaDb;
  let dbFilter = {};
  let partDbCheck = false;
  if(pmlaDbsTBC.checkAllDbs) {
    
  } else {
    partDbCheck = true;
    // prepare dbFilter
  }
  fullPmlaDb = await PmlaDb.find(dbFilter).lean().exec();

  
  for(id of investorIds) {
    const investor = await Investor.findById(id);
    if(!investor) continue;

    /// some sync code

      console.log( 'Started pmlaCheckForOneNew for ' + iName + ' at ' +
      new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-IN', { timeStyle: 'medium', dateStyle: 'medium', timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata' }).format(new Date()));

    let resData;

    /// calling method-3
    resData = await pmlaCheckForOneNew(fName, mName, lName, pan, country, isEntity, fullPmlaDb, partDbCheck, pmlaDbsTBC, dbData);


    if(resData) {
       /// some sync code
        
      pmlaCheck = new PmlaCheckNew(resData);
      await pmlaCheck.save();

        // more code to update investor record      
      await investor.save();

      let actionText = user.userName + ' performed PMLA check for ' + iName;
      const syslog = new Syslog ({
        logDate: new Date(),
        userId: user.acctId,
        userName: user.userName,
        action: actionText
      })
      await syslog.save()
    }  
    console.log( 'ENDed pmlaCheckForOneNew for ' + iName + ' at ' +
    new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-IN', { timeStyle: 'medium', dateStyle: 'medium', timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata' }).format(new Date()));


  }

}
```

**method-3**

```
async function pmlaCheckForOneNew(fName1, mName1, lName1, pan, country, isEntity, fullPmlaDb, partDbCheck, pmlaDbsTBC, dbData) {


  /// processes search operation 
    
  return { pmlaCheckResults, foundSearchTexts, pmlaCheckRemarks, pmlaCheckDbLevelSummary, pmlaCheckSummary, probeCode, nameScore }

}
```

**ERROR Details**

```
console output:
hemant STARTED NowPmlaCheckMany for 100 investors at 03-Oct-2023, 4:51:28 pm
Started pmlaCheckForOneNew for investor1 at 03-Oct-2023, 4:51:40 pm
ENDed pmlaCheckForOneNew for investor1 at 03-Oct-2023, 4:51:43 pm
Started pmlaCheckForOneNew for investor2 at 03-Oct-2023, 4:51:43 pm
ENDed pmlaCheckForOneNew for investor2 at 03-Oct-2023, 4:51:59 pm
Started pmlaCheckForOneNew for investor3 at 03-Oct-2023, 4:51:59 pm
ENDed pmlaCheckForOneNew for investor3 at 03-Oct-2023, 4:52:15 pm
...... more such console outputs
Started pmlaCheckForOneNew for investor38 at 03-Oct-2023, 4:52:21 pm
ENDed pmlaCheckForOneNew for investor38 at 03-Oct-2023, 4:52:38 pm
Started pmlaCheckForOneNew for investor39 at 03-Oct-2023, 4:52:38 pm
Error: write EPIPE
    at afterWriteDispatched (node:internal/stream_base_commons:160:15)
    at writeGeneric (node:internal/stream_base_commons:151:3)
    at Socket._writeGeneric (node:net:874:11)
    at Socket._write (node:net:886:8)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:392:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:333:10)
    at Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:337:10)
    at Connection.write (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:273:21)
    at /root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:1201:40
    at /root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:950:23
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError'
}
MongoError: pool is draining, new operations prohibited
    at Pool.write (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:849:8)
    at _command (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/wireprotocol/command.js:149:10)
    at command (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/wireprotocol/command.js:28:5)
    at Object.query (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/wireprotocol/query.js:70:3)
    at Server.query (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:649:16)
    at FindOperation.execute (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/find.js:38:12)
    at /root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:144:17
    at Server.selectServer (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:837:3)
    at Server.selectServer (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/topologies/topology_base.js:342:32)
    at executeWithServerSelection (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:131:12)
    at /root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:70:9
    at maybePromise (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:692:3)
    at executeOperation (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:34:10)
    at Cursor._initializeCursor (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/cursor.js:541:7)
    at Cursor._initializeCursor (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:190:11)
    at nextFunction (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/cursor.js:744:10)
    at Cursor._next (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/cursor.js:209:5)
    at /root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:253:14
    at maybePromise (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:692:3)
    at Cursor.next (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:238:12)
    at FindOneOperation.execute (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/find_one.js:29:14)
    at /root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:72:19
    at maybePromise (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:692:3)
    at executeOperation (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:34:10)
    at Collection.<anonymous> (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:1114:12)
    at Collection.deprecated [as findOne] (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:611:15)
    at NativeCollection.<computed> [as findOne] (/root/demo/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:244:33)
    at NodeCollection.findOne (/root/demo/node_modules/mquery/lib/collection/node.js:42:19)
```